# GET variable with SQL to get information from Database

Tags: php, sql

So I’m trying to create a website trough php that is connected to a database. It fetches through query’s to get information. The website is supposed to be about news, and I’ve come to a hold. I’ve managed to create an whole front page etc that fetches the news and shows them from the database, and when you use the navigation bar to the left(lnav) it shows specific news to what you have chosen(This is the first .php document). What I want to do now is make an individual article page. I want to show headline, introduction, body, date, author's name and title, file name, description and caption, on the page I would also like to use include getting the navigation bar to be linked from the first document called newswebb.php. Also the SQL queries are not in eng, if you need them translated I will edit it if needed 

These are the SQL queries I've writen to acomplish that

```
--  headers and preambles to Article 
SELECT Rubriker, Ingress, Brödtext, Publicerat 
FROM Artiklar 
WHERE ArtikelID IN (2);

-- 
-- I have retrieved "" name and title of all the article writer. '"
SELECT p.Namn, p.Titel, ae.ArtikelID
    FROM artiklar_anställda ae join
         anställda p
         on p.AnställningsID = ae.AnställningsID
    WHERE ae.ArtikelID IN (2);

-- 
-- specifies a article # 2
SELECT p.BildID, p.Filnamn, p.FotografNamn, ap.ArtikelID
FROM bilder p join
     artiklar_bilder ap
     on p.BildID = ap.ArtikelID
WHERE ap.BildID IN (2);
```

This is what I've got so far

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT artiklar.ArtikelID, artiklar.Rubriker, artiklar.Ingress, artiklar.Brödtext, artiklar.Publicerat, anställda.Namn AS Namn, anställda.Titel, anställda.AnställningsID
            FROM artiklar
            INNER JOIN artiklar_anställda
            ON artiklar.ArtikelID = artiklar_anställda.ArtikelID
            INNER JOIN anställda
            ON artiklar_anställda.AnställningsID = anställda.AnställningsID");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo '<div class="ingress">' . $row['Ingress'] . '</div>';

            echo '<div class="date">Publicerat: ' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['Publicerat'])) . '</div>';

            echo '<div class="rubrik">' . $row['Rubriker'] . '</div>';

            echo '<div class="artikel">' . $row['Brödtext'] . '</div>';

            echo '<div class="">' . $row['Namn'] . '</div>';
}


?>
```

But I cant get it to work

Comment: what error did you get? side note : mysql will be deprecated very soon, you should use mysqli for new code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is getting a single article out of the database through a get.

If that's the case:

Have an url:

```
http://www.url.com/page.php?article=5
```

Now you can go in your php file to retrive the article.

```
$articleId = $_GET['article'];
```

Now you use this variable within your query to select the article with the where clause:

```
WHERE article_id = $articleId
```

Sidenote:

Stop using mysql_* functions. Check the warning above: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Alternative: mysqli or PDO.

Also make you validate everything and prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

always secure GET/POST element before insert into any query.

```
$articleID = isset($_GET['article']) ? intval($_GET['article']) : '';
if(!$articleID)
{
exit("Invalid article id!");
}
//rest of code..
```